# Emgu.CV.Capture does not contain definition of RetriveBrgFrame

Tags: c#, emgucv

I am using Emgucv 3.0, and include all references and opencv.dll file correctly, but don not know why i can not retrieve frames using Capture object. following screen shot will illustrate my problem. if anyone know how to solve it.[Problem screenshot image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5O88.png)

Answer (score 1):

First,because there is no RetrieveBrgFrame in Emgucv 3.0, try to use Retrieve().

```
Mat mat = new Mat();

void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _capture.Retrieve(mat, 0);
    Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = mat.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
}
```